# Dynamical object re-allocation function

Tags: c++

it's been a long time since I have had to do this, and my hard drive from old school projects is in storage in some mystery box, so just wanting to make sure this is the proper way to do this?

```
void copyCharStack( StackAr<char>* stackIn_, int* sizeIn_ )
{
    StackAr(char)* tempCharStack( sizeIn_ + 5 );
    while( !stackIn_->isEmpty() )
    {
        tempCharStack->push( stackIn_->topAndPop() );
    }
    delete stackIn_;
    stackIn_ = tempCharStack;
    delete tempCharStack;
}
```

cheers, thanks!

Comment: Use a `std::vector<char>` or a `std::string` please.

Comment: Sorry should have clarified that I can't use STL for the assignment

Comment: You shouldn't use STL but the c++ standard library anyways. Your example isn't a [MCVE], which would allow comprehensive diagnosis.

Comment: You've created a variable sized array on the stack and now want to resize it. But if the library doesn't give easy, standard facilities for that, then the reason is that the stack may contain information after the variable array. So you can't resize without fiddling about with the internals. Which many systems won't let you do because its an open invitation to virus writers.

Comment: I guess `StackAr(char)` was meant to be `StackAr<char>`